# javafx event handler returning Error I don't fully understand

Tags: java, javafx

I'm fairly new to Javafx and trying to understand an Error I'm getting. When creating an event handler, the program is returning an Error: Error:(56, 94) java: -> expected.

Main.java

```
    package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Credit Card Input");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Controller.java

    package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;


public class Controller{
    @FXML
    TextField creditCardNo;
    @FXML
    TextField expDate;
    @FXML
    TextField ccvInput ;
    @FXML
    String imageOutput = new String("default.png");



    public String ccvCheck(Object ccvInput){
        String ccInput = this.ccvInput.getText();

        char[] intArray = ccInput.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder doubleDigitCheck = new StringBuilder();
        doubleDigitCheck.append(intArray[0]).append(intArray[1]);

        String str = new String(doubleDigitCheck);

        int checkValue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(intArray[0]));
        String str2 = ccInput.substring(0,1);
        if (str.matches("34")) {
            return imageOutput = new String("amex.png");

        }
        if (str.matches("35")) {
            return this.imageOutput = new String("jcb.png");
        }
        if (str.matches("37")) {
            return this.imageOutput = new String("amex.png");
        }
        if (str2.matches("4")) {
            return this.imageOutput = new String("visa.png");
        }
        if (str2.matches("5")) {
            return this.imageOutput = new String("mastercard.png");
        } else return this.imageOutput = new String("default.png");

    }

    public TextField getCcvInput() {
        return ccvInput;
    }

    EventHandler<? super KeyEvent> eventHandler= ccvInput.setOnKeyReleased(eventHandler -> ()   { ccvCheck(ccvInput); });
    //TODO:Set event handler to run checkValue and link to ccvInput


}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane prefHeight="119.0" prefWidth="321.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints />
    <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="160.5" minWidth="160.5" prefWidth="160.5" />
      <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="creditCardNo" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="expDate" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="ccvInput" onAction="#eventHandler" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
      <ImageView fx:id="imageOutput" fitHeight="72.0" fitWidth="105.0" opacity="0.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../visa.png" />
         </image></ImageView>
      <Label text="Credit Card Number" />
      <Label text="Exp Date" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <Label text="CCV" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

I'm trying to set the event handler so that when a user inputs numbers into the CVV Field(TextField ccvInput), an image is selected.  Currently receiving the error, which from my understanding. They syntax is correct. Any help understanding this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(eventHandler -> ()   { ccvCheck(ccvInput); })` – [that's not the correct syntax for lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax).

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way to create an `EventHandler`. You can use the lambda to define the `EventHandler` directly within the `setOnKeyReleased()` method:

```
ccvInput.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
    ccvCheck(ccvInput.getText());
});
```

You will likely run into many other issues with your code, however, and you might want to rethink your structure and flow.